# Get host from NodeJS request

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

I have a basic http server that runs on a server where multiple domains point to. I need to find the host of the request (the domain where the request is coming from).

```
 require("http").createServer(function (req, res) {
     console.log(req.headers.host);                
     res.end("Hello World!");                      
 }).listen(9000);
```

`req.headers.host`'s value is `127.0.0.1:9000` instead of the domain name (`example.com` or so).

How can I get the domain name from request object?

The node server is proxied via `nginx`. The configuration is like this:

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name ~.*;
   location / {
       proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9000;
   }
}
```

Comment: How is the node server proxied? nginx?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Exactly.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Don't forget to add an answer then. The issue is solved. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that `proxy_pass` in nginx rewrites the host header to whatever host is referenced in your rewrite. If you want to override that behavior, you can manually override the host header of the outgoing - proxied - request using `proxy_set_header`;

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name ~.*;
   location / {
       proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9000;
       proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
   }
}
```

A somewhat more detailed explanation is available [here](https://www.simplicidade.org/notes/archives/2011/02/nginx_proxy_host_header.html).